# Can I use the Chinese stroke order in Japan?

Tags: kanji

十 seems to unanimously start with the horizontal stroke.

but according to wiktionary, 田 starts with the horizontal stroke in China, but the vertical stroke in Japan.

How annoying! Different stroke order depending on which character the cross is in in Japan. It seems easier to use the Chinese stroke order.

Comment: As a Chinese writer myself, I would recommend using the Japanese stroke order regardless of other factors like getting scolded by teachers or being marked wrong in tests. Japanese stroke order is closer to the traditional Chinese calligraphy order, and is easier to transition to cursive (eventually being less tiring on the hands when you have to write long pieces of texts).